# HQSLDB -- File-Based Database Empty Even Though Files Have Content? Why?

Tags: spring, hsqldb

Folks,

### My Issue

Why is an HSQLDB file-based database I have pre-populated with a schema and data not populated when I connect to it later?

I think I'm missing some small, but **HUGELY IMPORTANT** configuration.

### My Environment

1. HSQLDB setup with the Maven Sql plugin and Maven Liquibase plugin.
2. Spring / Hibernate Webapp

### Steps to Populate the Database and Run the App

1. Run the Sql Maven plugin to create 3 schemas in the HSQL database
2. Run the Maven liquibase plugin, populating with ddl and lookup data

The jdbc url I'm using within Maven to setup hsql is:  `jdbc:hsqldb:file:${project.basedir}/target/db/build;shutdown=true`.
It translates to: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Users/myHomeDir/work/myProj/target/db/build;shutdown=true`

I have confirmed the the hsql database files are created and populated -- insert statements in the build.script file are present as expected.  I can connect to the database using RazorSQL and see the data and tables present.

#### Running the App

I've configured my DataSource in my Spring config as follows:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Users/myHomeDir/work/myProj/target/db/build;shutdown=true" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
```

I've fired up the app and see that Hibernate/Spring makes the connection to the database.  A database.lck file is created so I know the app has made a connection. (Also, I've ensured that RazorSQL is shutdown and not using the database at the same time).

### The Error

The error indicates that the database entities don't exist:

```
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.id as id5_2_,
        this_.created_date as created2_5_2_,
        this_.creating_user_id as creating3_5_2_,
        this_.email as email5_2_,
        this_.first_name as first5_5_2_,
        this_.is_enabled as is6_5_2_,
        this_.last_login_date as last7_5_2_,
        this_.last_modified_date as last8_5_2_,
        this_.last_modifying_user_id as last9_5_2_,
        this_.last_name as last10_5_2_,
        this_.login as login5_2_,
        this_.middle_initial as middle12_5_2_,
        this_.password_hash as password13_5_2_,
        this_.password_history as password14_5_2_,
        this_.suffix as suffix5_2_,
        roles2_.user_id as user1_5_4_,
        role3_.id as role2_4_,
        role3_.id as id3_0_,
        role3_.code as code3_0_,
        role3_.description as descript3_3_0_,
        role3_.name as name3_0_,
        role3_.type_id as type5_3_0_,
        roletype4_.id as id4_1_,
        roletype4_.description as descript2_4_1_ 
    from
        security.user this_ 
    left outer join
        security.user_role roles2_ 
            on this_.id=roles2_.user_id 
    left outer join
        security.role role3_ 
            on roles2_.role_id=role3_.id 
    left outer join
        security.role_type roletype4_ 
            on role3_.type_id=roletype4_.id 
    where
        this_.login=?
[01/20/2012 17:30:18,440] WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
[01/20/2012 17:30:18,440] ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - user lacks privilege or object not found: USER
2012-01-20 17:30:18.443:WARN::/my-webapp/j_spring_security_check
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure, can't it be caused by conflict of table name (`USER`) with SQL keyword?

Try to use different table name instead, or at least configure Hibernate to escape it (`@Table(name = "\"user\"")`).

Comment: Thanks for finding that needle-in-a-haystack.  Turns out that I had "user" and "role" tables that caused the problem.  I took a look at how to quote identifiers with hibernate: "You can force Hibernate to quote an identifier in the generated SQL by enclosing the table or column name in backticks in the mapping document. Hibernate will use the correct quotation style for the SQL Dialect. This is usually double quotes, but the SQL Server uses brackets and MySQL uses back ticks."  I wish there was a way to tell it to globally escape identifiers.